# Is it possible to allow the user to visually alter a graph?

Tags: d3.js, jsnetworkx

I created a simple graph (it will become more complex, but for the purpose of this example it will do):

```
function createGraph(){
  var graph = jsnx.Graph();
  graph.add_nodes_from([
[1,{color:'red'}],
[2,{color:'green'}],
[3,{color:'blue'}]
  ]);

  graph.add_edges_from([[1,2],[1,3]]);

  jsnx.draw(graph,{
element: '#my-canvas',
with_labels: true,
node_style:{
  fill: function(d){
      return d.data.color;
    }

}
   }); 
 }
```

This code successfully draws the graph. Now, I'd like the user to be able to select an edge with the mouse and, when this edge is selected, by pressing the "canc" key the edge should be deleted.

Also, if the user clicks on a node and then drags on another node, he should be able to create an edge.

In short: is d3.js just for visualization or does it allow to visually alter a graph too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In principle, you can do this with D3 (see [here](http://bl.ocks.org/rkirsling/5001347) for example). You will however have to implement the functionality that allows the user to change the graph yourself. That is, D3 doesn't provide this functionality out of the box.